# java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am getting an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

while reinitializing layoutInflater in onResume() like :

```
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I am trying to updatethe The content of view flipper. 
Can anyone suggest me the corrections in this to resolve the exception.

Comment: You're calling `getSystemService()` before `onCreate()` but the code you posted doesn't show where. See the exception stacktrace to see where you're calling it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behold:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context 
    //         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // NOT CORRECT
    LayoutInflater inflater; // correct

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context 
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // correct
    }
}
```